# Polynomial-time reducibility of Primality and 3-SAT

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete, np

Is 3-SAT $\leq_{p}$ Primality? And/or is Primality $\leq_{p}$ 3-SAT? I think the answer is no and yes, respectively, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you mean "Prime" with "Primality" (i.e. to know if a number is prime or not, which is in P :see the AKS article "Prime is in P").

Due to the NP completeness of the 3-SAT problem, I think your question:

- is Primality ≤p 3-SAT

has TRUE like an answer, like you think. In fact every problem in NP can be reduced to 3-SAT in polynomial time, so every problem in P also, because every language in P is also in NP.

The other statement,  3-SAT ≤p Primality, would imply Primality to be NP-Complete and is not know for the moment.
Anyway IF SO, P = NP because Primality is NP-Complete and Primality is in P.